# I need to count the average of each day's records and size in MB for each file created in a day. For a whole year

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I ask for your help after several unsuccessful attempts.

I am learning with PL SQL. I am using Oracle SQL developer v.20

I have this situation. My data set looks like this:

```
id_file     size_byte   created_at
_________   _________   ____________________________
1               45323   17-FEB-22 17:21:13,726874000
2               41232   17-FEB-22 17:21:13,740587004
3             1234456   20-FEB-22 17:25:13,368874058
4           233545488   20-FEB-22 17:21:18,400049000
5           233545488   21-FEB-22 18:11:18,058746868
```

So my desired output would be something like this for year 2022:

```
TOT_records     AVG_file_created_for_day     TOT_size_files     AVG_size_files_created_each_day
___________     ________________________     ______________     _______________________________
9.999.999       10.000                       999.999.999        5 MB (default is byte)
```

ID is type NUMBER, SIZE_BYTE is type NUMBER, CREATED_AT is TIMESTAMP(6)

My table is partitioned for each year, PARTITION_DATE is type DATE

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - have result that matches the given sample data.

Comment: MB (traditionally in IT) is `bytes/power(1024,2)`. For GB use `power(1024,3)` etc. Strictly speaking in modern standards, a megabyte is `bytes/1e6` and the traditional `bytes/power(1024,2)` version is called a [Mebibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Multiple-byte_units).  I've never heard of that being used in IT, though.

Comment: By the way, this is SQL not PL/SQL, and SQL Developer isn't relevant to the query you are writing.

Comment: @jarlh I using Oracle...

Comment: @jarlh I didn't understand, what should I simplify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some ambiguity on things like "average file size per day"... That could be:

- sum all file sizes / total number of days, or
- average of files size per day, then take average of that average

Anyway, here's some stuff to get you going (I'm assuming the latter above)

```
SQL> create table t as
  2  select
  3    rownum id_file,
  4    dbms_random.value(1000,20000000) bytes,
  5    date '2021-01-01' + dbms_random.value(1,700) created_at
  6  from dual
  7  connect by level <= 5000;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> select * from t
  2  where rownum <= 20;

   ID_FILE      BYTES CREATED_A
---------- ---------- ---------
         1 19305636.7 02-SEP-22
         2 6305773.83 10-OCT-21
         3 11939117.8 04-NOV-21
         4 11039507.9 01-SEP-21
         5 15555516.8 02-NOV-22
         6 2809048.47 13-SEP-22
         7 2070381.41 18-DEC-21
         8 11116786.1 11-MAR-22
         9 17519679.8 21-DEC-21
        10 6728222.84 02-APR-22
        11 7569442.31 07-AUG-22
        12 16949454.2 06-JUL-21
        13 8019443.02 03-JUN-21
        14 13147674.9 31-AUG-21
        15 14590702.5 16-JUL-22
        16 13028609.7 11-MAY-21
        17 5466477.07 06-APR-22
        18 4469902.12 08-MAY-21
        19   14511096 31-MAY-22
        20 5245726.03 12-JUL-21

20 rows selected.

SQL> select
  2    count(*) total_records,
  3    avg(daily_size_avg)/1024/1024 avg_size_files_per_day_mb,
  4    sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 tot_bytes_gb,
  5    avg(files_per_day) avg_files_per_day
  6  from
  7  (
  8  select
  9    bytes,
 10    avg(bytes) over ( partition by trunc(created_at) ) daily_size_avg,
 11    count(*) over ( partition by trunc(created_at) ) files_per_day
 12  from t
 13  );

TOTAL_RECORDS AVG_SIZE_FILES_PER_DAY_MB TOT_BYTES_GB AVG_FILES_PER_DAY
------------- ------------------------- ------------ -----------------
         5000                 9.5313187   46.5396421             8.092
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This query work very good!